# R: extract the latest revisionTime for each date

Tags: r, loops, date, dataframe, revision

I have a revision data frame with 3 columns:

1. revisionTime
2. date
3. value

For instance here is a sample, but mine is very very long (several hundred of thousands of rows)

```
df = structure(list(revisionTime = structure(c(1471417781, 1471417781, 
1471417781, 1473978576, 1473978576, 1473978576), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), date = structure(c(1464652800, 1467244800, 
1469923200, 1456704000, 1467244800, 1472601600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), value = c(103.7, 104.1, 104.9, 104.414, 
104.3, 104.4)), .Names = c("revisionTime", "date", "value"), row.names = 536:541, class = "data.frame")
```

What I need is a very fast way to extract from this data.frame the latest revisionTime for each date (and the corresponding value). There are some similar questions, but my question is more precise: **is there a way to avoid loops**?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'date' after converting to `Date` class, `order` the 'revisionTime' in descending order (in `i`) and get the first row with `head`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[order(-revisionTime), head(.SD, 1), .(date = as.Date(date))]
```

Comment: Wouldn't `df%>%group_by(date)%>%summarise(lastrevisionTime=last(revisionTime))` from `dplyr`work?

Comment: @Haboryme  Here, you are assuming that revisionTime is ordered,  YOu may need `arrange` in between.

Answer (score 0):

If your revisionTime is nicely formatted (Y-m-d H:M:S) always as in your example, you may not need to convert to Date time at all, this should simply work:

```
aggregate(revisionTime ~ date, df, max)
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I have then to `plyr::join` the 2 data.frames to get the corresponding values?

Comment: Do you have a 2nd data frame too?

Comment: ok my mistake as I read again my question: I actually need `the value` corresponding to the latest revisionTime, hence my misunderstanding of your answer.

Comment: max will give you the latest revision time for each date.

Comment: indeed. then I can merge or join with the original data.frame to get the corresponding value. Thanks